# Get all Commands without arguments from history (with Regex)

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, command

I have just started with learning shell commands and how to script in bash.
Now I like to solve the mentioned task in the title.
What I get from `history` command (without line numbers):

```
ls [options/arguments] | grep [options/arguments]
find [...] exec- sed [...]
du [...]; awk [...] file
```

And how my output should look like:

```
ls
grep
find
sed
du
awk
```

I already found a solution, but it doesn't really satisfy me. So far I declared three arrays, used the `readarray -t << (...)` command twice, in order to save the content from my history and after that, in combination with `compgen -ac`, to get all commands which I can possibly run. Then I compared the contents from both with loops, and saved the command every time it matched a line in the "history" array. A lot of effort for an simple exercise, I guess.

Another solution I thought of, is to do it with regex pattern matching.
A command usually starts at the beginning of the line, after a pipe, an execute or after a semicolon. And maybe more, I just don't know about yet.
So I need a regex which gives me only the next word after it matched one of these conditions. That's the command I've found and it seems to work:

```
grep -oP '(?<=|\s/)\w+'
```

Here it uses the pipe `|` as a condition. But I need to insert the others too. So I have put the pattern in double quotes, created an array with all conditions and tried it as recommend:

```
grep -oP "(?<=$condition\s/)\w+"
```

But no matter how I insert the variable, it fails. To keep it short, I couldn't figure out how the command works, especially not the regex part.

So, how can solve it using regular expressions? Or with a better approach than mine?

Thank you in advance! :-)

Comment: You can do it by this way.  `history | awk -F' ' '{print $4}'` Instead of $4 add column number in which your commands lie..

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and works quite well

```
history -w /dev/stdout | cut -f1 -d ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk` with `fc` command:

```
awk '{print $1}' <(fc -nl)
find
mkdir
find
touch
tty
printf
find
ls
```

`fc -nl` lists entries from history without the line numbers.